# JQuery prependTo() create extra space between div(s)

Tags: jquery, html, css, clone

## The problem

I'm trying to prependTo a `clone()` div to an existing set of div and the experencing a strange problem. The Div seems to create extra space bettween the divs like so. There probably a hack by reformating the html but I don't really want to do that.

> > > > [image]

#### This is the code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="resources">
    <div class="template">
        <p>Hi <b>Bob</b></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="template">
        <p>Hi <b>Bob</b></p>
    </div><div class="template">
        <p>Hi <b>Mark</b></p>
    </div>
</div>

<button>Add Another Box</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.resources {
    display:none;
}

.template {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:1px;
}

.content {background-color:red}
```

#### JQuery

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('.resources .template').clone()
        .find('b').html("joe").end()
        .prependTo(".content");
});
```

---

#### JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7Kmex/1/

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with `inline-block` elements.  If there is space between the elements, a space is displayed between the elements.

A common fix for this is to set the `font-size` of the container to `0`.  In this way, the space will take up no space:

```
.template {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:1px;

    font-size: 8pt;
}

.content {
    background-color:red; 
    font-size: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Kmex/5/

Alternatively, in this specific situation, you can simply remove the space before your first div tag:

```
<div class="content"><div class="template">
        <p>Hi <b>Bob</b></p>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Kmex/6/

Answer (score 2):

I think it is caused because you are using `display:inline-block`. It can sometimes happen that there is somewhere an empty character that shows as your extra whitespace.

I tries some techniques from this site http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

To remove whitespaces between inline-block elements try to set font size of your `.content` element to `font-size: 0px`

```
.content {
    background-color:red; 
    font-size: 0px;
}

.template {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:1px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

here I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Kmex/8/

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space before the first `.template` like this, as the space in the html remains after you add the first additional `inline-block` element and spaces between `inline-block`s get rendered to 4px by browsers.

```
<div class="content"><div class="template">
        <p>Hi <b>Bob</b></p>
    </div><div class="template">
        <p>Hi <b>Mark</b></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kmex/7/)